# Vue 3 - Composition API - How to return information from getters

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-composition-api

I have the following code (check below). But I get an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: getStatus is not a function
```

The question is: How to make sure this works? I'm transferring from `Options API` to `Composition API`.

**VUEX**

```
get getStatus() {
 return (object: any) => {
  console.log(object)
  return this.data[object.route].find(status => status.id === object.id)
 };
}
```

**Code**

```
export default defineComponent({
 name: "",
 props: {
  processingData: Object
 },
 components: {
  Flag
 },
 emits: ["unique", "refresh"],

 setup(props, {emit}) {

 const store = useStore()
 const getStatus = computed(() => store.getters.getStatus)

 function setStatus(id, route) {
    const object = {
        id: id,
        route: route
    }
    return getStatus(object);
 }

 return {
  getScope,
  setUniqueId,
  getClass,
  getWidth,
  navigatePagination,
  setStatus,
  setTag
};
}
```

Comment: please share the code of vuex store file

Answer (score 0):

A getter in vuex is just a normal function specified in the vuex store. However your vuex code sample shows `getStatus` as a JavaScript getter. A JavaScript getter is a way to call a function when an object properties value is looked up. It is specified by the `get` keyword followed by the function you would like to be called when looking up said value. Declaring a JS getter for an object property does **not** make the property a function.

```js
const obj = {
    value: "",
    get getValue() {return this.value + "!"},
};

obj.value = "Hey";

console.log(obj.getValue) // logs 'Hey!'
obj.getValue() // TypeError: obj.getValue is not a function => getters are not callable
```

The getter you specify gets called when you look up the value of the specified property. You do not call it yourself.

In the case of Vuex getters it is handled differently. Here getters are just functions that return a computed value *when called*.

The solution to your problem would therefore be to define your getter as a method, not a JS getter.

Comment: You don't need to change getter cause it doesn't change state, just getting some filtered info from state

Comment: The getter specified by nhatimme is not callable. All the computed property does is return the (still not callable) getter. In `setStatus`, the getter returned by the computed property `getStatus` is called, leading to the error. So you either need to change the getter or stop calling it, as it is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

```
return store.getters.getStatus(object);
```

This makes the solution.